# how to find word vertically in a crossword

Tags: python, python-3.4

I'm trying to write a function that accepts a 2-dimensional (2D) list of characters (like a crossword puzzle) and a string as input arguments, the function must then search the columns of the 2D list to find a match of the word. If a match is found, the function should then return a list containing the row index and column index of the start of the match, otherwise it should return the value None.

For example if the function is called as shown below:

```
crosswords = [['s','d','o','g'],['c','u','c','m'],['a','c','a','t'],['t','e','t','k']]
word = 'cat'
find_word_vertical(crosswords,word)
```

then the function should return:

```
[1,0]
```

Comment: I dont understand the output, why [1,0]?

Comment: Hi,the reason for [1,0] is because the search word is 'cat' and the first occurrence of the first letter of 'cat' which is 'c' is at index 1 of crosswords and at index 0 of index 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
def find_word_vertical(crosswords,word):

    columns = []
    finished = []
    for col in range(len(crosswords[0])):
        columns.append( [crosswords[row][col] for row in  
        range(len(crosswords))])

    for a in range(0, len(crosswords)):
        column = [crosswords[x][a] for x in range(len(crosswords))]
        finished.append(column)

    for row in finished:
        r=finished.index(row)
        whole_row = ''.join(row)
        found_at = whole_row.find(word)
        if found_at >=0:
            return([found_at, r])
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is for finding horizontal... could switching this around help?

```
def find_word_horizontal(crosswords, word):

    list1=[]
    row_index = -1
    column_index = -1
    refind=''
    for row in crosswords:
        index=''
        for column in row:
            index= index+column
            list1.append(index)

    for find_word in list1:
        if word in find_word:
            row_index = list1.index(find_word)
       refind = find_word
       column_index = find_word.index(word)


    ret = [row_index,column_index]
    if row_index!= -1 and column_index != -1:
        return ret
```

Comment: anybody able to help with this?? i am unable to figure out the vertical part myself...

Comment: Thanks Aleksander, but I now have this figured out, will post my answer here in hope it helps anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

The simple version is:

```
def find_word_vertical(crosswords,word):
    z=[list(i) for i in zip(*crosswords)]   
    for rows in z:          
        row_index = z.index(rows)
        single_row = ''.join(rows)      
        column_index = single_row.find(word)        
        if column_index >= 0:
            return([column_index, row_index])
```

This gives correct output [1,0]

Answer (score 0):

To find a word vertically:

```
def find_word_vertical(crosswords,word):
if not crosswords or not word:
    return None
for col_index in range(len(crosswords[0])):
    str = ''
    for row_index in range(len(crosswords)):
        str = str + crosswords[row_index][col_index]
    if temp_str.find(word) >= 0:
        return [str.find(word),col_index]
```

Answer (score 0):

To find a word Horizontaly:

```
def find_word_horizontal(crosswords, word):
if not crosswords or not word: 
    return None
for index, row in enumerate(crosswords):
    str = ''.join(row)
    if str.find(word) >= 0:
        return [index,str.find(word)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#find vertical word in 2d
```

def find_it(li,wo):
out_list=[]

```
for row in range(len(li)):
    print(row)
    chek_word=""
    for item in range(len(li)):
        chek_word=chek_word + li[item][row]
    print(chek_word)
    if wo in chek_word:
        print(chek_word.find(wo))
        out_list=[ chek_word.find(wo) , row]
        print(out_list)
        break
```

this is mine and yes it work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
def find_word_vertical(crosswords,word):
    if not crosswords or not word:
        return None    
    number_of_columns=len(crosswords[0])
    for col_index in range (number_of_columns):
        temp_str=''
        for row_index in range(len(crosswords)):
            temp_str=temp_str+crosswords[row_index][col_index]
        if temp_str.find(word)>=0:
            return [temp_str.find(word),col_index]
    return None
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including a detailed explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.