# Find word vertically from 2D crosswords or 2D lists

Tags: python, list, puzzle

I have written some python code to find row and column indices from a 2D crossword, searching vertically. My code is:

```
def find_word_vertical(crosswords,word):
    l=[]
    for i in range(len(crosswords[0])):
            l.append(''.join([row[i] for row in crosswords]))
            print(l)            
            if word in l:   #finding index
                row_index=crosswords.index(i)
                column_index=i.index(word[0])
                print(row_index,column_index)
                return [row_index,column_index ]
    return None
crosswords=[['s','d','o','g'],['c','u','c','m'],['a','c','a','t'],['t','e','t','k']]
word='cat'
print(find_word_vertical(crosswords,word))
```

My code is currently returning `None`, but it should be returning the index values `[1,0]`.

How can I get column index and row index correctly from crosswords for selected word(cat)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def find_word_vertical(crosswords,word):
    z=[list(i) for i in zip(*crosswords)]   
    for rows in z:          
        row_index = z.index(rows)
        single_row = ''.join(rows)      
        column_index = single_row.find(word)        
        if column_index >= 0:
            return([column_index, row_index])
```

I modified the codes and this code give me correct index [1,0]

Comment: Was the problem that `column_index` and `row_index` were the other way around in your original?  Also, please ensure that if any other answers *helped* you in preparting **this** answer - [StackOverflow best practice on answering is to acknowledge them as such](http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).

Comment: Yes, the problem was to find out column_index and row_index. The link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35755116/how-to-find-word-vertically-in-a-crossword/35825013#35825013 help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

The [crux](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/crux) of the issue with your code is some misuse of the [Python list `index` method](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).  Specifically, upon line #7 of the code (as posted).
you appear to be using `index` to perform a list lookup (normally done using the square braces `[]`).

**Additionally**, you also appear to have some [type confusion (which is easy when starting in a loosely typed language such as Python)](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/) happening.  This occurs because the `l` variable (which I'm *assuming* was a shorthand for line?) is a `list`, not a string.  Because of this, the condition `word in l` would **never** be true - hence making your program ALWAYS `return None` as if no match existed.

---

### Code:

The below code works:

```
def find_word_vertical(crosswords,word):
    l=[]
    for i in range(len(crosswords[0])):
            l.append(''.join([row[i] for row in crosswords]))
            for line in l:
                if word in line:   #finding index
                    row_index=i
                    column_index=line.index(word[0])
                    return (row_index,column_index)
    raise Exception("Unable to find word vertically!")

crosswords=[['s','d','o','g'],['c','u','c','m'],['a','c','a','t'],['t','e','t','k']]
word='cat'

print(find_word_vertical(crosswords,word))
```

### Changes:

1. Added the `for line in l:` loop (line #5), this gets around the type-confusion issue you were having.  <sub>**Note**:  There may be *other* (possibly **better**) ways around this.</sub>
2. Changed `row_index` to just be set to `i` - since we're **already** iterating in that dimension with that variable.
3. Changed `column_index` to make use of `line`, rather than `i` (which is just a counter).
4. This one wasn't *technically* necessary, and you may wish not to use it.. but I removed the `return None` and replaced this with an Exception (better practice for an unexpected algorithmic result).

---

### Other Recommendations:

- Your "main" style code (*i.e.* the definition of `crosswords`, `word` and the print line which calls your function) would **best** be put into an `if __name__=="__main__":` block.
- Avoid single letter variable names (like `l`) for **important** things (like what you're using `l` for here).  I would change this to be `vertical_line` or similar.
- The argument you supply to `range` in the first `for` loop, makes the **assumption** that *all crossword lines are the same length*  You have no logic anywhere I can see to enforce this.

---

When you are done with your program, please consider [posting it on the Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site for review.

Comment: Thank for pointing me the short comings of my codes. I tested your code it return [0,1] instead of [1,0]. Your advice will certainly help me in future coding.

Comment: You're most welcome.  Yes, as I stated in my comment on your answer -  in your original question `column_index` and `row_index` were the other way around to begin with (hence why my code returns [0,1]).

Answer (score -1):

Your code is returning `None` because on line 11 you **literally** `return None`.

I suspect you mean to be `return`ing `l`?